# Change variable from HTTP Response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a `GET` request from where I extract the variable `${SAMLRequest}` (Regular Expression Extractor).

Value of `${SAMLRequest}` is as follows: `VhJUVNXeHBPRjNMdnNvNHpTUT09PC9YNTA5Q2VydGlmaWNhdGU+PC9YNTA5RGF0YT48L0tleUluZm8+PC9TaWduYXR1cmU+PHNhbWxwOk5hbWVJRFBvbGljeSBBbGxvd0NyZWF0ZT0idHJ1ZSIgLz48L3NhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4=`

Next I have a `POST` request, and I want to post the variable `${SAMLRequest}` with some changes.

Instead of the sign `+` I want to have `%2B` and instead of `=`, I want to have `%3D`.

Do you know how I can change a variable in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Use **beanshell preprocessor**[1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) in your post sampler

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check "Encode?" box for `SAMLRequest` parameter in your POST request body

The harder way is using [__urlencode()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) JMeter Function.

The hardest way is [BeanShell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as okwap suggests. However it'll give you the full control.

Relevant Beahshell code will look like:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

String source = vars.get("SAMLRequest");
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(source);
vars.put("SAMLRequest", encoded);
```